# Does this contain a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, memmove

Does the code below contain a memory leak. I suspect it does but the tools I use to detect them(Visual Studio + Parasoft c++ test) aren't flagging up anything. If it is how would I fix it?

```
//A dynamically allocated array of char pointers
int numOfStrings = 10, numOfChars = 32;
char** data = new char*[numOfStrings];

//Generate each each individual string
for(int i = 0; i <numOfStrings; i++)
    data[i] = new char[numOfChars];

//moves the elements 1-5 in the array to the right by one
int index = 1, boundary = 5, sizeToMove = (boundary - index) * sizeof(numOfChars);
memmove(&data[index + 1],&data[index],sizeToMove);

delete[] data;
```

EDIT:

I should mention, I have tried iterating over each individual string as below but an exception occurs.

```
for(int i = 0; i< numOfStrings; i++)
    delete [] data [i];
```

Comment: @NuclearGhost: No, it shouldn't.  This question is about identifying and correcting a specific problem in a piece of code.  Code review is for when you have a piece of code for which you want suggestions for improvement in any area.

Comment: Do not use `new`; It is better to use `std::vector`, or in the case of `char`s, `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. When you are deleting

```
delete[] data;
```

You are releasing the memory allocated for data. However the memory allocated

```
data[i] = new char[numOfChars];
```

is still not freed.

You have to iterate over `data` and delete each `data[i]` before deleting data.

Generally you should make sure you have as many `delete`s as `new`s.
**Here you have `numOfStrings + 1` `new`s and only one `delete`.**

**One more leak**

Since you are doing

```
int index = 1, boundary = 5, sizeToMove = (boundary - index) * sizeof(numOfChars);
memmove(&data[index + 1],&data[index],sizeToMove);
```

*(You are not moving shifting five places as you thought but 4 places `(5 - 1 = 4)`)*

After this operation

```
data[2] will get the value of data[1]

data[2] <- data[1]
data[3] <- data[2]
data[4] <- data[3]
data[5] <- data[4]
```

**And what was pointed to by `data[5]` will be lost.

`data[2], data[1]` will have the same value (point to the same place)**

This can also explain why you are getting segfault when you want to delete by iterating over `data`

Comment: I've already tried doing that but an exeption occurs. I've updated the original post with the code.

Comment: you should do it before deleting `data`

Comment: That's where I placed it when I tried it. It's the first call to delete[] data[i] within the loop that causes the exception

Comment: I have edited it again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have a leak!

You have to delete each pointer in the array before deleting the pointer pointing to them.

```
//delete each array
for(int i = 0; i <numOfStrings; i++)
    delete[] data[i];

//this is a single pointer, not an array
delete[] data;
```

Now you won't have a leak

Comment: That's what I originally assumed I should be doing but it causes an exception when I enter the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment and why you changed `delete[] data;` to `delete data;` -- Yes, it is a single pointer, not an array.  You don't use `delete` or `delete[]` on arrays, you use them on pointers.  But it points to the first element of a dynamically allocated array. `char** data = new char*[numOfStrings];` -- So `delete[] data;` was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: for every 'new', there MUST be a corresponding 'delete' call. You don't have that, so you have a leak.